# How to render a Map in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, rendering

I see lots of people converting data to arrays with methods not possible to me as far as I can see.

I am using react and typescript and have a very simple map that I wish to render as a list of buttons

Here is what I have so far

```
const renderPlayerChoice = (indexMap: Map<number, number>) => {
    // What I would like to do if it was possible
    return indexMap.map((key, value =>{
    // do stuff here
    return stuff
    }) 
}
```

But the map function does not exist for this object it only has a foreach which does not return any results

Comment: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) doesn't implement a `map()` method, but you can map its [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries). `return [...indexMap.entries()].map((key, value) => ...` (Map.entries() returns an iterator so you have to spread it into an array)

Comment: It is complaining when I do this with:
`TS2569: Type 'IterableIterator[number, number]>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.`

I am unsure where the compiler option exists (I did not setup the project)

Comment: It looks like you're compiling to es5 so you'll either need to target es6 or set `"downlevelIteration": true` in compilerOptions. (though if you're targeting es5 you don't get Map at all)

Comment: Try with this: `[...indexMap.entries()].map(([key, value]) =>`. The `key, value` are now within square-brackets `[]`. It is my understanding that `.entries()` returns something like so: `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2], [k3, v3],.....]` & hence iterating over this may be done using `[k, v]`. Please share feedback so I may update myself if my understanding is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Like [so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtjAvDMBTA7jAsgQwA4A80ATgJZgDmANCgK5wBGqxAfABQCUA3ALABQcAHQRUUNgHIc4mgGZu-ISLHiG0mABZ5fUJBAAbVIL0gKbAILFiOAJ6CAZsRBw2cDoLj42bANoBrGgBuALocSCwwAAYAJADevgC+ALSxAfERHFpAA):

```
return Array.from(indexMap).map(([key, value]) => {
    // do stuff here
    return stuff;
});
```